# страницы взависимости от роли

Tags: laravel, laravel5

есть две роли пользователей : Преподаватели и ученики

как в зависимости от роли кидать на определенный роут?
во вьюхах или можно как-то сделать в роуте?

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'sd-admin'], function(){
    Route::get('/', 'AdminController@login');
    Route::post('/', 'AdminController@isLogin')->name('adminLogin');
    Route::get('/search-teacher', 'SearchTeacherController@adminShow')->name('searchTeacher');
    Route::get('/search-student', 'SearchStudentController@adminShow')->name('searchStudent');
    Route::get('/users', 'UserController@adminShow');
    Route::get('/search-teacher/add/{id}', 'SearchTeacherController@addTeacher');
    Route::get('/search-student/add/{id}', 'SearchStudentController@addStudent');
    Route::post('/search-teacher/add', 'SearchTeacherController@saveTeacher')->name('saveTeacher');
    Route::post('/search-student/add', 'SearchStudentController@saveStudent')->name('saveStudent');
})
```

Comment: через middleware: создаете 2 middleware (Преподаватели и ученики) и вешаете их на роуты

Comment: можно создать хелпер который в зависимости от роли выдает маршрут

Comment: а как вызвать хелпер? и поработать с ним?